# Wrapping minitest test blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using minitest with rails 3.2. I want to define my own "test" function that does some special stuff, then proceeds as normal.

Normally, you define tests like this:

```
class MyControllertest < ActionController::TestCase                        
  test "should note have defined x" do
    assert(!(defined? x))
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I would like to be able to do the following

```
class MyControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase                        
  special_test "should define X" do
    assert(defined? x)
    get :index
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

So, I tried the following in a test helper that I include

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase    
  def self.special_test(name)                                                                                                                                                    
    self.test(name) do                                                                                                                                                           
      x=1
      yield                                                                                                                                                                     
    end                                                                                                                                                                            
  end    
end
```

But, I get

```
undefined method `get' for MyControllerTest:Class
```

Can someone help teach me a little about metaprogramming / how to go about this?

https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's weird cause in the test example, you're showing test which sublcass `ActionController::TestCase` but you're defining your method in `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, define your custom method in `ActionController::TestCase` if that's what you want.